# eclipse navigate showing java source in directory hierachy instead of package

Tags: eclipse

Due to some reason I found, when displaying the source ,my navigator changed from the right side (preferred) to the left side , which need more clicks to access the source file. I remembered that I did accept some chance unconsciously which result in this unpleasant change but can not find a way go back...

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best friend in eclipse is CTRL+3 (quick access), press that and then search for what you want, try perspectives and views, see below.

### Perspectives

Check what perspective you are in (now).  In the top right of eclipse there is a list of perspectives.  Sometimes when you carry out an action it asks you if you want to change perspectives.  This can change your views/layouts.  You might want the Java or Java EE perspective.

### views

There are multiple views of your files.  What is the name of the tab where ComputeBench is showing up?  Try opening the "Project Explorer" or the "Package Explorer" views.

Comment: +genius! I was using navigator ,should have used "Package Explore"